# Add on click with javascript to img created with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a javascript function that creates multiple divs containing images and applies an onclick event to each one.  When you click on the image, it should open the respective web page; however, it seems that the function applies the same onclick event to each one (it doesn't differentiate between each image).

Here is the code:

```
function UpdateDock() {
    $.get("apps", function(data){
        var Dock = document.getElementById("Dock");
        var Apps = JSON.parse(data);

        for (var App in Apps) {
            if (Apps[App]["Dock"] == "1") {
                // Create a box to store the application
                var ApplicationBox = document.createElement("div");
                ApplicationBox.className = "App"

                // Put the icon inside the box
                var Icon = document.createElement("img");
                Icon.src = `static/images/ApplicationIcons/${Apps[App]["Folder"]}.png`;
                Icon.id = Apps[App]["URL"];

                Icon.onclick = function() {OpenApplication(Icon.id)};

                // Put the icon in the box and the box in the dock
                ApplicationBox.appendChild(Icon);
                Dock.appendChild(ApplicationBox);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Jquery accesses a route on the server to get the web pages (Apps) that are to be displayed in a div at the bottom of the screen (Dock).
2. This route sends a json object that specifies which web pages are available, which ones to show, and the respective URL's.
3. A div is created to store the image associated with the application so that it can be aligned.
4. An image is inserted into the div.
5. An onclick event is added to the image so that it will open the respective url when clicked (I do need this to be an onclick event - as it opens it within an iframe embedded in the same page).
6. The div is inserted into the dock.

This works well when there is only one Application (web page), but when there is more than one application, they all port to the same onclick url.  On the server side, the applications are retrieved in alphabetical order (they are read from the filesystem), and it seems that the url being attached to all applications is the same as the first one.  For example, if I have the apps "Banana" and "Cat", both will open the page "Banana".

I could try changing the "OpenApplication" function to open the url based on the sender's id (which can be named appropriately when added to the loop), but I would need a way to reference the sender.  Here is the current function:

```
function OpenApplication(Application) {
    // Changes the active application and animates the transition
    var ActiveApplication = document.getElementById("ActiveApplication");
    console.log(Application);
    ActiveApplication.style.animation = "Hide 1s";
    ActiveApplication.src = Application;
    ActiveApplication.style.animation = "Show 1s";
}
```

Rather than pass Application as a variable, is there a way I could reference which onclick event activated the function?

I guess there are two questions here:

1. What is wrong with my loop?  Why is it applying the same URL to every application?
2. Could I solve this by referencing the sender in the OpenApplication function?  If so, how would I reference the sender?

Comment: Maybe you can use event delegation? https://javascript.info/event-delegation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your callback of the click listener , you will get the event parameter , and you access to it's target that is basically the element that happened the event

You can use **one** of this two ways

**First way:**

```
icon.addEventListener('click' , event => {
  const {target} = event
  //Now target does reference to the element that happened the click
  OpenApplication(target)

})
```

**Second way**

```
Icon.onclick = function(e) {OpenApplication(e.target.id)};
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, but your suggestion is quite ambiguous.  I cannot tell by reading it or looking at the code how I should change my application.

I added an event listener to the Icon variable, but this had the same result as what I was doing originally.

Comment: Thank you, I'm still a bit confused though.  Your statement (event => {const {target} = event}) is unclear.  Where does it go in the program (and where does the onclick go)?  Also, target is never declared, should I be using OpenApplication in place of target?

Comment: Also, the (event => ...) statement doesn't have enough arguments.

Comment: @BobZed By accident I didn't add the 'click' , fixed now , and you don't need to use both ways , is just different ways to archive the same thing , I updated my answer and I think it's everything more clear now